# Visual Studio 2013 is not able to recognise the class file added as Add > Existing Item > File "Add as link"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I am trying to add an external C# file. It's added to the project but the IDE is not able to recognize the class, even the class name is not reflected into the intellisence option. I am working on a c# desktop application on VS2013.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suspect that the newly added `class` is inside the different `namespace` than from where you are trying to access it.

if that is the case just try to access the newly added `class` using its `namespace` asbelow:

```
namespace newlyaddednamespace
{
  class newclass
  {
     //this is the class added newly
  }
}

namespace mynamespace
{

 class myclass
 {
   //access the newly added class from its namespace
   newlyaddednamespace.newclass newclassObj=new newlyaddednamespace.newclass();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Build Action` for that file to `Compile`.